# Error while throwing User defined exception using orElseThrow in java 8

Tags: java, java-8, option-type, throw

I am trying to throw an custom excpetion using `orElseThrow` java 8 command. However I am getting the following compile errors:

```
public class UserInvitationServiceImpl implements UserInvitationService{

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public void inviteUser(String email) throws UserNotFoundException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(email!= null && !email.isEmpty()) {
            Optional<User> optionalUser = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
            optionalUser.orElseThrow(new UserNotFoundException("User doesnt exist in system"));
        }
    }       
}

public interface UserInvitationService {   
    void inviteUser(String email) throws UserNotFoundException; 
}
```

And my custom exception class, UserNotFoundException which extends RunTimeException is as follows:

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class UserNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9093519063576333483L;

    public UserNotFoundException( String message) {
        super(message);
    }    
}
```

I am getting this error at `orElseThrow` statement:

> The method orElseThrow(Supplier) in the type
>   Optional is not applicable for the arguments
>   (UserNotFoundException)

What is the issue here and how to throw custom user defined exception via `orElseThrow`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it should be a supplier:

```
.orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException("User doesnt exist in system"));
```